# Caption in figure and cross-reference them properly

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to know how should I cross-reference the following caption in manuscript in following way Fig 1a and Fig 1b.

```
\begin{figure}
\minipage{0.50\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.50\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2}
\endminipage\hfill

 \caption{$(a)$ taghyer jabejaei: $R$ is the reference configuration and $D$ is the deformed configuration and $(b)$ Salam Khub hasti density $\bf f$ agr bashe en ro dorost kard force density $\bf t$ at both points} \label{fig:m}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: There is a big difference between "citing" and "referencing". The former typically refers to items inside a bibliography, while the latter uses a `\label`-`\ref` approach. Could you include a complete, minimal example that highlights your setup? We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: From just your example, it seems you could use the `subfig` package and the normal `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

Comment: @ Werner, it is complicated to copy-paste here however I have used this Fig.~\ref{fig:m} in order to cite the figures into manuscript. The issue is I do not know how to distinct this between 1a and 1b. Please guide me how I can have Fig1a and Fig1b in to manuscript.

Comment: @ Dan, where should I use that subfig..the figures are located in side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you load the [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption) package, which provides an environment called `subfigure`. I further suggest you load the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package to help streamline making cross-references to items such as subfigures.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption} % provides 'subfigure' environment
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref} % for "clever" cross-referencing
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
  \caption{First subfigure} \label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}\hfill% leave no blank line between subfigures
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2}
  \caption{Second subfigure} \label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{A figure with two subfigures} \label{fig:1}

\end{figure}

\noindent
A cross-reference to \cref{fig:1b}.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you don't need to cross-reference the subfigures individually, and if you're fine with providing a long caption that describes the contents of the two image files, there's certainly no need to load the `subcaption` package or to place the image files in `minipage` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref} % for "clever" cross-referencing
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{fig1}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{fig2}

\caption{Left-hand panel: taghyer jabejaei, $R$ is the reference configuration and $D$ is the deformed configuration. Right-hand panel: Salam Khub hasti density $\mathbf{f}$ agr bashe en ro dorost kard force density $\mathbf{t}$ at both points} \label{fig:m}
\end{figure}

\noindent
A cross-reference to \cref{fig:m}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Mico, this is good but I do not want to use this format. I like to have one caption but cite that in manuscript as Fig 1a and Fig 1b.

Comment: @Mohammad - Please clarify: If you have only one caption, how can it be referred to alternately as "Fig 1a" and "Fig 1b"?

Comment: @ Mico, in the figure "a" and "b" are boxed (for example). It seems that LaTeX can cite this only and only if we have two figures.  in other words, there is one cite corresponding each figure. does it make sense?

Comment: @Mohammad - "does it make sense?" I'm afraid not. If you want to cross-reference the entire figure, type `\cref{fig:1}`; if you want to cross-reference the subfigure, type `\cref{fig:1a}`, say. If you think you'll never need to cross-reference one or the other subfigure, don't use `subfigure` (or `minipage`) environments to begin with.

Comment: Okay, it does works now.

Comment: @Mohammad - I've posted an addendum showing a solution that doesn't require either `subfigure` or `minipage` environments.